# Extra output in for php in html hello world file

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a LAMP stack and just started learning PHP. I'm having trouble with my Hello World program. On my server I have a file called index.html. This is the contents of that file (which is basically copy pasted from an online guide):

```
<html>
 <title>HTML with PHP</title>
 <body>
 <h1>My Example</h1>

 <?php
 echo '<p>Hello World</p>';
 ?>

 <b>Here is some more HTML</b>

 </body>
 </html>
```

When opened on a web browser, I *expect* my output to look something like this:

```
My Example

Hello World

Here is some more HTML
```

Instead, it looks like this:

```
My Example

Hello World

'; ?> Here is some more HTML
```

Why is that extra "'; ?>" there? I'm probably making a simple mistake. I've tried accessing index.html on chrome, firefox, and safari, same result each time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**PHP** does not work in **HTML** files, try renaming it to index.**php**

Apart from that the code is fine (maybe some best practices like separating HTML and PHP, but you'll get to that later)

The reason you don't see the whole PHP code on your screen is because the browser is trying to parse the element `<?php *** ?>` as if it where valid HTML (like `<span>`). If you check the html-source, you will see all of your code.

---

As someone in the comments below mentioned, there are ways to make PHP work in HTML. You should not do this, unless you are very aware of what you are doing. It is not a default setting and it should stay that way. If you should be able to use PHP in HTML files, .phpfiles would not have to exist.

When you expand your knowledge, you will start separating HTML files from PHP files and make PHP include templates. Two separate files for two separate goals

Comment: That all depends on server configuration. It's trivial to configure a web server (and many are) to parse .html files the same as .php. And it looks like his web server may be set up to parse .html files, otherwise the entirety of the PHP code, including `<?php` and `echo` should have been included in his output as well, but according to his post they were not.

Comment: You can make php work in html, yes. But this is not a default setting. And you should keep it that way, unless you know what you are doing. If using php in html would be a good idea, a `.php` file would not have to exist :)

Answer (score 1):

Rename the file to index.php.

In addition to this, the PHP code must be interpreted by a WEB SERVER(Apache in your case).

For example(if you are using XAMPP on Windows), and your php file is present in the webcontent directory of your server's document root(htdocs), then type the following in your browser

`http://localhost/htdocs/webcontent/index.php.`

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, you must rename `index.html` to `index.php`, but if you must use `index.html`, put the line below into your `.htaccess` file, so you can process `.html` files as `.php`.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```